# Do a specific query for each row of a table, one by one

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table:

```
| key1 | key2 | value |
+------+------+-------+
| 1    | 1    | 1337  |
| 1    | 2    | 6545  |
| 2    | 1    | 213   |
| 3    | 1    | 131   |
```

What I would like to do is traverse this table row by row, then using the key two values in further queries (all other tables contain the unique combination of these two keys + other data)

How do I do this kind of thing in SQL?

**EDIT**: I would want to extract key1, key2 from row 1 (1,1) then do a query on it, which would result in a number.

Then I would move to the second row, an identical query which would again result in a number.

All of these numbers would be then inserted into a pre-prepared view.

**EDIT2**: I need to traverse it because the specific use of my database.

It is a database of planets which contains sectors (the keys are the IDs of these two). All of these sectors contain resources, turrets and walls.
The table I have in my post is an example of table of sectors, with the value being enemy force.

Table of resources, turrets etc. contain these two keys so they are linked to and only to a specific sector.

I need to go row by row so I can use this keys to select only specific resources/turrets/walls from my tables, aggregate them and then subtract them from the value in my sector table. Resulting number would then be inserted into a pre-prepared view (again, into the row which matches the combination of my two keys)

Comment: Please add the expected output along with the logic of you expect it to be obtained.

Comment: Why to traverse? You could get all data with single query.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a correlated subquery or lateral join.  You don't have that much explanation, but something like this:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 cross join lateral
     (select . . .
      from table2 t2 . . .
      where t2.key1 = t1.key1 and t2.key2 = t1.key2
     ) t2
```

You are not clear on what the second query looks like.  The `where` clause is called a *correlation clause*.  It connects the subquery to the outer query.  A correlation clause is not strictly needed for this to work.

The columns from the outer query can be used elsewhere in the subquery.  I am just assuming that an equality condition connects the two (lacking other information).